# Buildings in three.js

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I am working on a web game and using three.js to do the 3d of the game. I am building a city and I want the buildings to look exactly like the picture below.

[image]

I want them to be a base material, without textures or colors because I will add colors later depending on the building status (like the game below).

This is what I have right now:

[image]

As you can see, I just have a bunch of different-sized boxes, with no details at all. How would I achieve the details seen in the game?

This is my current code:

```
export default function Map() {
  const RenderBuildings = () => {
    const buildings = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      buildings.push(<Box color="#dad3cb" width={1} height={1} depth={1} />)
    }

    return buildings
  }

  return (
    <Canvas>
      <CameraController />
      <ambientLight intensity={1} />
      <Ground color="#b0aa9d" width={40} height={1} depth={40} />
      {RenderBuildings()}
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export const Box = (props: Props) => {
  const { color, width, height, depth, ...rest } = props

  const mesh = useRef<THREE.Mesh>()
  const boxRef = useRef<THREE.Mesh>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mesh.current) return

    const _mesh = mesh.current

    _mesh.position.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    _mesh.position.z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)
    _mesh.scale.x =
      Math.random() * Math.random() * Math.random() * Math.random() * 5 + 3
    _mesh.scale.z = _mesh.scale.x
    _mesh.scale.y =
      Math.random() * Math.random() * Math.random() * _mesh.scale.x * 5 + 3
  }, [mesh])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!boxRef.current) return

    const _boxRef = boxRef.current

    _boxRef.applyMatrix4(new Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0.5, 0))
  }, [boxRef])

  return (
    <mesh {...rest} ref={mesh}>
      <boxGeometry args={[width, height, depth]} ref={boxRef} />
      <meshToonMaterial color={color} />
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step should be to look at lighting your scene. This will allow for better depth to your buildings. A hemisphere light may be your best bet: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_hemisphere. You can learn more about lights here: https://threejs.org/manual/#en/lights.

Next, take a look at geometry. You want those buildings to have some level of detail at the geometry level. You can use primitives like these: https://threejs.org/manual/#en/primitives or build a model in any modelling software and import it in. At that point, maybe make a few models and then instance them randomly.

Depending on how you do geometry, you will need to pick an appropriate material: https://threejs.org/manual/#en/materials. This should give you plenty of options.

I would also add in a bit of animation to keep things lively: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes

Finally, a bit of fog always helps for ambiance: https://threejs.org/manual/#en/fog

Some more inspiration: https://demos.littleworkshop.fr/infinitown

Ultimately, building a scene like this is going to be a labour of love. There are no easy shortcuts. Keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

Use a texture tile(s) to coordinate the layout (like a QR code but unencrypted). That is, a ~64x64 image with RGB values which correspond to scene logic. This method will be easier to block in features. You can store height in R, type in G, and owner in B. Maybe there is a sidecar file with more raw data (i.e. bills or level), referenced by owner and x/y.

Map generation could be defined by: matrix, random forest, evolutions... with rules for  adjacent tiles and minimum areas. Then once you have a satisfactory system, it can be parsed as a Three.js scene. Geometry can be as easy or as hard as you make it. Extrude contiguous pixel groups & refine.

Don't forget to add dust clouds when you synchronize the data to obscure visual artifacts. You can probably do a lot with texture offsets in terms of variety, from a forced perspective.